# Last Modified Date formula in Excel that updates when a specific cell value changes (from non-blank)

Tags: excel, datetime, if-statement, excel-formula, formula

[Excel data set with formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiBSt.png)
Please see the attached image of my spreadsheet for reference.

I am trying to build a better version of the formula: =IF(B3<>"",IF(D3<>"",D3,NOW()),"")

In its current form, this formula updates cell D2:D with function **NOW**, but only when the field is updated from a **blank expression** in B3. As seen in the image posted, there are multiple Stages to our process, and we'd like the Last Modified field to be able to update to **NOW** if a new value is input over a currently populated field in B and not just from a blank.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `NOW()` function will run every time you made any changes to the sheet. What is your actual goal?

Comment: @Harun24hr when I change the Order Status in Column B from say "Shipped" to "Delivered," I want the Last Modified Date to change to the moment when I made that change. In it's current form it only does that if B was changed from Blank, but I would like it to work if B is not currently blank

Comment: u want the =now() value to 'stick' when u open the file tomorrow.. not to change everytime u open the workbook right? so I guess the best is to insert the current time using https://www.exceldemy.com/how-to-insert-current-date-and-time-in-excel/ or https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-the-current-date-and-time-in-a-cell-b5663451-10b0-40ab-9e71-6b0ce5768138

Comment: If I changed cell B4 from "Shipped" to "Delivered," I'd want the date in D4 to update from 7/27/2023 to 7/28/2023 to show when the last time B4 was updated